# Question on Plane Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

I'm currently reading S.L Loney's book on plane trigonometry, and have stumbled upon a conceptual impasse. If someone could kindly read through this page:[image]

I haven't been able to concretely grasp the method of proof that is presented here. Specifically this part: [image]

How exactly is it inferred that $(\theta + \alpha)/2$ is equal to any odd multiple of $\pi/2$? Or that $(\theta - \alpha)/2$ is equal to any multiple of $\pi$? Could someone please elucidate this idea to me? Thank you in advance

Comment: You just have to observe the graphs of $\sin$ and $\cos$ to see this

Comment: @DavidQuinn I believe there is an trigonometrically algebraic method to understand this.

Comment: Here , we have " $2\cos(x)\sin(y)=0$ " , which implies " either $\cos(x)=0$ or $\sin(y)=0$ " , which implies " either $x=\cos^{-1}(0)$ or $y=\sin^{-1}(0)$ " , which then implies " either $x=...$ or $y=...$ " : Does that resolve the confusion ?

Comment: @Prem yes, thank you. It appears I have failed to see such obvious demonstration. Excuse my blunder. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For an easier geometric interpretation of the combination of the two solution angles terminating at $(A,B)$ note that

the first case is their *internal* bisector radius vector lies along multiples of $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ in red,

and that

the second case is their *external* bisector radius vector lies along multiples of $\pi$ in green.

These vectors should also be mirrored about x- and y- axes in the full solution. (but not shown).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For $\cos \dfrac {\alpha + \theta}{2} = 0$, $\alpha + \theta$ must be odd to get the solution $\dfrac {\pi(2k+1)}{2}$.  For $\sin \dfrac {\alpha - \theta}{2} = 0$, $\alpha - \theta$ must be even to get the solution $\pi k$.

Comment: Ahh, how foolish of me to miss such obvious demonstration. Thank you for elucidating it so clearly.

Comment: I've corrected my post, but the way I'm reading your response it seems you're not satisfied with the answer (and it sounds patronizing).  If the answer is good, accept it.  If it's not, please point out where you want clarification.

Comment: I'm truly sorry, I wasn't trying to sound patronizing. I've observed that $cos$${\alpha + \theta} \over 2$$= 0$ translates to the fact that the smallest positive angle that ${\alpha + \theta} \over2$ could be is  90, i.e. $\pi \over 2$. Hence, the general expression for all angles having the same cosine would be $2\pi n \pm$ $\pi \over 2$. This can be further simplified into $(4n\pm 1)$$\pi \over 2$. Since $4n \pm 1$ is the same as $2n + 1$, it is evident that the angle resembles an odd multiple of $\pi \over 2$. I found the sine angle similarly. Thank you for your answer and attention, again!

Comment: Glad you found the result...I was thinking about this afterwards and maybe I was a little too abrupt.  My apologies!